# getCanonicalPath with NFS needs Authentication

Tags: java, io, nfs

Using the `java.io package` on a mounted NFS file system is transparent for most methods (creating and writing files, setting read only flag etc.). But `getCanonicalPath` (File class) can throw an IOException because a separate authentication is required - and missing. 
What is worse, is that it is not clear how this authentication is achieved. Does it depend on the mount only or must the account of the client process match a registered NFS user? So far, we have contradicting experience, concerning the same NFS server!
Does anyone have more details about the authentication procedure used implicitly by getCanonicalPath?
(I am still talking about jre 1.6, the Java 7 implementation might be different).